# Mvc: Getting the selected value of the dropdownlistFor box

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

In my domain I have this service

```
    public class StudentService
        {
            private readonly IStudentRepository _studentRepository;

            public StudentService(IStudentRepository studentRepository)
            {
                _studentRepository = studentRepository;
            }

            public StudentDto DisplayStudentInformation()
            {
                var objStuSec = _studentRepository.DisplayStudentSection();
                return objStuSec;
            }  
        }
```

Here is my studentDto

```
    public class StudentDto
        {
            public string StudentId { get; set; }
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
            public List<DepartmentDto> GetAllDepartments;
        }
```

Here is my code for the Home controller

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
        {
            private StudentService _objStudentService;

            public HomeController(StudentService objStudentService)
            {
                _objStudentService = objStudentService;
            }

            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "This is a Test";

                var displayform =  _objStudentService.DisplayStudentInformation();

                return View(displayform);
            }     
        }
```

Here is my html for the form

```
    @using System.Net.Mime
    @model Zakota.University.Domain.DTO.StudentDto

    <form action="" method="post">

        <div>
            <label>First Name</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.FirstName, new { id = "testid1", name="firstname" })
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Last Name</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.LastName, new { id = "testid1", name="lastname" })

        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Email Address</label>     
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.EmailAddress, new { id = "testid1", name="emailaddress" })
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Department</label>
            @Html.DropDownListFor( x=> x.GetAllDepartments,new SelectList(Model.GetAllDepartments,"DepartmentId","DepartmentDescription"), new {@class = "mydropdown", name="dept"})
        </div>
        <div>
            <label></label>
            <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
        </div>  

    </form>
```

I want to be able to get the selected value of the department from dropdownListFor box. I am getting null as the selected value.
Please assist. All other values are correct. The code below is part of the controller code. I just decided to separate it.

```
      [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Index(StudentDto objstudent)
            {

                string strFirstName = objstudent.FirstName;
                string strLastName = objstudent.LastName;
                string strEmailAddress = objstudent.EmailAddress;
                string strDept = Request.Form["dept"];

                var displayform = _objStudentService.DisplayStudentInformation();

                return View(displayform);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `<select>` element postback a single value. You cannot bind a `<select>` to a collection of complex objects (in your case `List<DepartmentDto>`). Start by creating a view model representing what you want to edit

```
public class StudentVM
{
  [Display(Name = "First Name")]
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your first name")]
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  .... // other properties of StudentDto 
  [Display(Name = "Department")]
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a department")]
  public int SelectedDepartment { get; set; }
  public SelectList DepartmentList { get; set; }
}
```

Next, your `StudentDto` model should not contain a property containing a collection of all departments. Your use of `DropDownListFor()` suggest each student has only one Department, therefore the property should be `public DepartmentDto> Department;

Controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  StudentVM model = new StudentVM();
  ConfigureCreateViewModel(model);
  return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(StudentVM model)
{
  if(!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    ConfigureCreateViewModel(model); // reassign the select list
    return View(model); // return the view so user can correct errors
  }
  StudentDto student = new StudentDto()
  {
    FirstName = model.FirstName,
    LastName = model.LastName,
    EmailAddress = mdoel.EmailAddress,
    Department = db.Departments.Find(model.SelectedDepartment) // modify to suit
  }
  // save StudentDto and redirect
}

private void ConfigureCreateViewModel(StudentVM model)
{
  List<DepartmentDto> departments = // call a service to get a collection of all departments
  model.DepartmentList = new SelectList(departments, "DepartmentId","DepartmentDescription");
}
```

View

```
@model yourAssembly.StudentVM
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName)
  .... // other controls of StudentVM
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedDepartment)
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedDepartment, Model.DepartmentList, "--Please select--")
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedDepartment)
  <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
}
```

Side notes:

1. Use `@Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName)` rather than `<label>First
   Name</label>`. A `<label>` is an element associated with a control
   (clicking on it sets focus to the associated control) - you usage
   does nothing because it is missing the `for` attribute
2. The html helper methods correctly give the elements an `id` and
   `name` attribute. In you case you are generating invalid html by
   creating duplicate `id` attributes (the first 3 elements have
   `id="testid1"`) and you should never attempt to set the `name`
   attribute (in the first 3 cases, your just setting it to what it
   already is anyway, but in the case of the dropdown, you trying to
   change it to `name="dept"` which fortunately does not work - because
   if it did, binding would fail!)
3. You should also consider adding validation attributes to your view
   model properties, e.g. `[Required(ErrorMessage="Please enter a first
   name")]` and in the view including `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m =>
   m.FirstName)`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I followed your steps and everything is looking good.
  The only problem I am having now is on the click of the create button
  when I do a post, I am getting a null value for DepartmentList

Comment: You need to reassign the value of DepartmentList if you return the view (which you should only be doing if ModelState is invalid anyway). Generally its best to use a `private void ConfigureViewModel(StudentVM model)` method that sets the value of `SelectLists` (and other common values) that you call in the GET method, and again in the POST method if you return the view.

Comment: Please can you show me a code sample of how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot. What I mean is when I set a break point on the method public ActionResult Index(StudentViewModel model), DepartmentList = Null. It is always Null meaning that I don't have the value selected from the dropdownlist. I am able to get the departmentId though.

Comment: `DepartmentList` will always be null. You don't (and should not) generate any controls for each property of the `SelectList`. The `DepartmentId` of the selected option is bound to the `SelectedDepartment` property.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help. I appreciate it. One last thing. If I decide to save the DepartmentDescription, what will I change?

Comment: A `<select>` only posts back a single value (in this case `DepartmentId`). You need to look up the `Department` based on the selected `DepartmentId` value and then assign that to to the model (for example `Department = db.Departments.Find(model.SelectedDepartment)`.

Comment: Thanks again. Appreciate it.